# I can't access all the elements of the application using pyatspi

Tags: python, python-3.x

I understand the automation of application testing on linux (specifically using Ubuntu 20). I need to access all the elements of the installer application (just an application with a GUI to automate the installation of some utilities). My code:

```
import pyatspi

def print_accessible(accessible, padding=""):
    if accessible is not None:
        role = accessible.getRoleName()
        name = accessible.name if accessible.name else "Without a name"
        print(padding + role, name)
        for child in accessible:
            print_accessible(child, padding + "  ")


desktop = pyatspi.Registry.getDesktop(0)
installer_app = None
for app in desktop:
    if app.name == "installer":
        installer_app = app
        break

if installer_app is not None:
    print_accessible(installer_app)
else:
    print("installer not found.")
```

In this case, I only get the output:

```
 application installer  
  frame installer
```

At the same time, if I use the Accerciser utility and click on the specified application inside Accerciser, then after executing my code, the output will already be like this:

```
application installer
  frame installer
    panel Without a name
      panel Without a name
        panel Without a name
          panel Without a name
            panel Without a name
              panel Without a name
                panel Without a name
              document web installer
                section Without a name
                  section Without a name
                    push button Automatic installation/update
                    push button Installation/update with settings
```

In the first case, the first element "panel Without a name" is defined by me as None and I can no longer access its child subelement, but after activating the installer in the Accerciser program, I get all the elements for output.

The question is, how can I get all the window elements without using Accerciser? Or maybe I can "activate" the window through Accerciser using the console command and then get a list of all the elements

I also tried to use it at the beginning of my code

```
wmctrl -a "installer"
```

But such activation of the window did not lead to anything.